CMAKE header only project needs to compile with lower cpp standard
I have a HEADER-ONLY older project that must compile with c++14 or older versions with the gcc compiler.
My project however must use c++17 or newer.
How can I make it work?
Tried compiling to a static library with CMAKE but that will not work since most of the code is in .h and .hpp files which CMAKE does not want to compile to a static lib

A header file is not compiled standalone. It is compiled as a part of the source file. You cannot compile a source file using one C++ standard and compile a header using another standard.
